# What is the instruction length for Register Direct addressing modes?

Tags: cpu-registers

My question is What is the instruction length for Register Direct addressing modes?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Unclear what are you asking, but for x86, instructions are variable length.

`push eax` is a 1 byte.

`mov eax, ebx` is 2 bytes.

`mov ax, bx` is 3 bytes

`movaps xmm0, xmm1` is 3 bytes.

All 4 above instructions directly address these registers.